# Is there any dataset having word by word translation of the Quran?

Tags: quran, translation

I am looking for a dataset of all the Quranic words translation in English. In some websites, there seems to have that but they do not provide download option.

For example,

http://corpus.quran.com

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Comment: Would this be helpful?

http://tanzil.net/download/

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81: Thank you. I have seen that link. It provides translation of verses in different languages. I was looking for word by word translation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is no different than book recommendation which is off-topic here. Read [more...](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/261/what-is-our-stance-on-book-recommendations?s=1|2.2583)

Comment: This is not book recommendation. This is specifically asking for a "dataset".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.openburhan.com/) might be useful. You can download the site from [here](http://www.openburhan.net/installob.zip)

Comment: There's a `note.txt` inside the ZIP file stating "Please note that:All data presented here has not been verified. Please refer to authentic translations for accuracy." Might need more information on this matter before using the data.